# MYSQL+Hibernate, Query cannot be created

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Can someone help me to have a look at what is wrong with my query?

**Java code :**

```
public boolean fValidLogin(String fUsername, String fPassword) {
    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    String query = "SELECT fusername,fpassword FROM flogin WHERE fusername=" + fUsername + " AND fpassword=" + fPassword + "";
    Query DBquery = session.createQuery(query);
    for (Iterator it = DBquery.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
        it.next();
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Total rows: " + count);
    if (count == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**MYSQL Code:**

```
SELECT fusername,fpassword FROM flogin WHERE fusername="SAS" AND fpassword="Sas123"
```

Comment: Try this first: "SELECT fusername,fpassword FROM flogin WHERE fusername=\"" + fUsername + "\" AND fpassword=\"" +fPassword +"\""
By the way you are tring to use a native query. Maybe you should use "createNativeQuery" instead of "createQuery"

Comment: What error do you get? Post the full stack trace please

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a victim of an **SQL Injection**, it can also cause **syntax error**, instead you have to use [setParameter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) with a JPQL query :

```
String query = "SELECT f FROM flogin f WHERE f.fusername = ? AND f.fpassword = ?";
Query dBquery = session.createQuery(query);
dBquery.setParameter(0, fUsername);//set username variable
dBquery.setParameter(1, fPassword);//set password variable
```

To get the nbr of result you can just call [Query::list()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list())

```
int count = dBquery.list().size();
```

Or just :

```
return dBquery.list().size() == 1;
```

---

The real problem in your query is that the String should be between two quotes (**but i don't advice with solution**)

```
fusername='" + fUsername + "'
//--------^_________________^
```

Note: Your query is not a JPQL Query, it seems a native query, if that you have to use `session.createNativeQuery(query);`.

Comment: Thanks YCF_L but when I tried to use your code, I got this error: StandardWrapperValve[forwardServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet forwardServlet threw exception
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: flogin is not mapped [SELECT fusername, fpassword FROM flogin WHERE fusername=:fUsername AND fpassword=:fPassword]

Comment: @Kkr0319 read the answer again, I think you tried my first version ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

```
"SELECT fusername,fpassword FROM flogin WHERE fusername=\"" + fUsername + "\" AND fpassword=\"" +fPassword +"\""
```

By the way you are tring to use a native query. Maybe you should consider to use "createNativeQuery" instead of "createQuery"